# How to get licensed COM object via CreateInstanceLic?

Tags: c, com

I'm trying to access com of licensed server, so I'm using IClassFactory2 to do
so. Here is my code so far:

```
// ...
IClassFactory2 class_factory;
hr = CoGetClassObject(
    &clsid,
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    NULL,
    &IID_IClassFactory2,
    (LPVOID*) &class_factory
);
if (hr != S_OK) { return 1; }
// ...
hr = class_factory.lpVtbl->CreateInstanceLic(
    &class_factory,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &IID_IDispatch,
    key,
    (LPVOID)&dispatch
);
// ...
```

However, the call to `CreateInstanceLic` segfaults.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00000001 in consoleapplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001.
```

I think reason is that `class_factory.lpVtbl` looks like this:

```
    QueryInterface  oleaut32.dll!0x75769edc (Type information missing from symbol file) HRESULT(__stdcall*)(IClassFactory2 *, const _GUID * const, void * *)
    AddRef  0x00000001  unsigned long(__stdcall*)(IClassFactory2 *)
    Release 0x00401074  unsigned long(__stdcall*)(IClassFactory2 *)
    CreateInstance  0x003f67a0  HRESULT(__stdcall*)(IClassFactory2 *, IUnknown *, const _GUID * const, void * *)
    LockServer  0x003e777c  HRESULT(__stdcall*)(IClassFactory2 *, int)
    GetLicInfo  0x003e7778  HRESULT(__stdcall*)(IClassFactory2 *, tagLICINFO *)
    RequestLicKey   0x757e60c4 {oleaut32.dll!_gPFactory}    HRESULT(__stdcall*)(IClassFactory2 *, unsigned long, wchar_t * *)
    CreateInstanceLic   0x00000001  HRESULT(__stdcall*)(IClassFactory2 *, IUnknown *, IUnknown *, const _GUID * const, wchar_t *, void * *)
```

I kinda get the feeling that 0x00000001 is not a valid address where `CreateInstanceLic` should be located. So I'm probably doing something wrong but have no idea what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it should be:

```
IClassFactory2 * class_factory;
hr = CoGetClassObject(
    &clsid,
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    NULL,
    &IID_IClassFactory2,
    &class_factory
);
if (hr != S_OK) { return 1; }
// ...
IDispatch * dispatch;
hr = class_factory.lpVtbl->CreateInstanceLic(
    &class_factory,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &IID_IDispatch,
    key,
    &dispatch
);
```